# siunitx preserve thousand's spacing for squared

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I am using the `siunitx` package and I am trying to achieve a mix of 1) and 2):

[image]

meaning that I want the spacing between the digits to be as in 1) but I also want it to be squared, as in 2).

So far I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale = DE ,
  group-digits = true,
}

\begin{document}

\SI{362880}{\second}                    % spacing is correct, but without squaring - see 1)
\SI[exponent-base=362880]{e2}{\second}  % squaring is correct, spacing is not - see 2)
\SI{362880\squared}{\second}            % does not work
\SI{362880^2}{\second}                  % does not work either

\end{document}
```

can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here works but looks both imho a bit unnatural.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale = DE ,
  group-digits = true,
}

\begin{document}

\SI{362880}{\second}                    % spacing is correct, but without squaring - see 1)
\SI[exponent-base=362\,880]{e2}{\second}  % squaring is correct, spacing is not - see 2)
\SI[exponent-base =,exponent-product=]{362880e2}{\second}            % does not work

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not very friendly, but…

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale = DE ,
  group-digits = true,
}

\begin{document}

\SI{362880}{\second}

\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\num[parse-numbers=true]{362880}^2}{\second}

\end{document}
```

[image]